# Angular Google Maps custom marker with Infowindow & Wepback

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-google-maps

We're migrating our Angular app to Webpack, and we had some problems with Angular Google Maps.
The last one is the custom InfoWindow we are defining in our map.

Before (with gulp) the code was working, and the definition of the marker was:

```
    angular.forEach(sidemap.ads, function (ad) {
      var marker = {
        id: ad.id,
        latitude: ad.gps.latitude,
        longitude: ad.gps.longitude,
        options: {
          labelClass: 'marker-label',
          labelAnchor: '15 28',
          labelContent: ad.price + sidemap.currency,
          icon: '../../../../assets/png/marker.png'
        },
        show: false,
        templateUrl: '../../../../modules/ads-search/offers/map/ad.map.html',
        templateParameter: ad
      };
      sidemap.markers.push(marker);
    });
```

When we migrated to Webpack, we changed `templateUrl` to `template` with a `require`:

```
    angular.forEach(sidemap.ads, function (ad) {
      var marker = {
        id: ad.id,
        latitude: ad.gps.latitude,
        longitude: ad.gps.longitude,
        options: {
          labelClass: 'marker-label',
          labelAnchor: '15 28',
          labelContent: ad.price + sidemap.currency,
          icon: require('../../assets/png/marker.png')
        },
        show: false,
        template: require('../../modules/ads-search/offers/map/ad.map.html'),
        templateParameter: ad
      };
      sidemap.markers.push(marker);
    });
```

The marker appears correctly in the map, but when trying to click on it, we get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined` in the `createInfoBoxDiv_` function of Angular Google Maps.

I think it's probably related to the template parameter, it seems that [the template parameter exists in the definition](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/65cfba14502795568e7f0042534792ecdeef36f2/src/coffee/directives/api/i-window.coffee) but we must be doing wrong obviously, because it's not working.

Any ideas?